# Configre QEMU(Emulator) for xilinx SDK

Tags: qemu, sdk, xilinx

I am using Xilinx Vivado and Xilinx SDK for simple program on ZYNQ FPGA/MP Ultra Scale. but i havn't the hardware device(Development board). So i tried to configure the Qemu to run the SDK program.
Any help regrading this will be appreciated.

Comment: QEMU is not an emulator. What are you tryng to emulate, and why?

Comment: i am new in hardware development, so i tried to run Xilinx sdk projects (say hello world ) in QEMU. is this possible . assuming i havn't the Xilinx board(dev_board)